# Is this a bug in the documentation? -existingObjectWithID:error: or -objectWithID: seem to claim different things that don't match

Tags: iphone, core-data

From the docs: -existingObjectWithID:error:

> If there is a managed object with the
>   given ID already registered in the
>   context, that object is returned
>   directly; otherwise the corresponding
>   object is faulted into the context.
>
> This method might perform I/O if the
>   data is uncached.
>
> Unlike objectWithID:, this method
>   never returns a fault.

Well, this is paradox!

They say that -existingObjectWithID:error: may return a fault ("faulted into context"). And at the same time, they say that -objectWithID: does return a fault, but -existingObjectWithID:error: does not. So what's true now? Both method descriptions talk about returning faulted objects.

Can someone clear that up?

Comment: No need to post this question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006394/

Comment: @Emil - This is not a duplicate. It ask a related but different question.

Comment: @Tech Posted at the same time?

Comment: @Emil - They are still two separate questions. It doesn't matter if he asked them at the same time. That's why no ones voted to close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Faulted does not mean "make into a fault". It actually means, "create a full fledged object" the opposite of what you expect. In other words, a faulted object is not a fault. The nomenclature is confusing.

It arises because of the term "to fire a fault" from the old DB days. In that term you took a fault i.e. the ghost of an object and "fired" it thus causing it to load its attributes. This got shorten from "firing the fault" to "faulting" which a naive reader/listener would assume means "to make into a fault."

In training, I've used the term "ghost" as a synonym for fault and "materialize" for faulting. It helps clear up the terminology and expresses my childhood love of Scooby-Do at the same time.