# How to pass a ManagedObjectID to the main thread

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsmanagedobjectid

I am saving a ManagedObject on a background thread with its own context. I would then like to send a notification back to the main thread with the managed object context so that I can use its data.

According to the docs it looks like I instead should be passing the id to the main thread rather than the object.

Is this correct, what should I do with that Id then? Should I do a fetch on core data from the main thread with the ID to get a ManagedObject on the main thread?

Comment: an MO cannnot be transfer between threads. That would break the containment. Use the objectID like shown below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in understanding the passing of the object ID back to the main thread. Once you've done that, use the `objectWithID:` method, passing the `NSManagedObjectID` sent from the other thread, to get the object out of the main thread's `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

```
NSManagedObject *objectForThisThread = [managedObjectContextForThisThread objectWithID:managedObjectID];
```

Comment: Will objectWithID fetch the object from disk if the context does not already have it?

Comment: What sets the value of the NSManagedObjectID? I am creating an object of a NSManagedObject subclass I have, and once saved I want to need to send the ID, but I did not set the ID. Does it get set in the save method?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. I'll try to address the whole flow later tonight as I'll have to do a little research to give you the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to use the following method

```
- (NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID error:(NSError **)error
```

This method never returns a fault for that object.

In your back thread do a save. Using that method will allow to retrieve the object saved in background.

See [`NSManagedObjectContext` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html).

Comment: @Helium3 see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006394/whats-the-difference-between-existingobjectwithiderror-and-objectwithid