# Correct use of MagicalRecord to save in BG

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I've seen two different ways of doing this and I'd like to know which is correct.

Specifically I'm talking about accessing the `ManagedObject` on the BG thread.

The methods I have seen are...

```
Person *person = ...
[MagicalRecord saveUsingBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    Person *localPerson = [person inContext:localContext];
    // do stuff...
}]
```

But I've also seen...

```
Person *person = ...
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = person.objectID;
[MagicalRecord saveUsingBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    Person *localPerson = (Person*)[localContext objectWithID:objectID];
    // do stuff...
}]
```

The latter seems more correct as you're not trying to access the object across threads. But having seen both I wasn't sure if `MagicalRecord` did something Magical to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inContext:` is a Magical Record "shorthand" for `MR_inContext:`, and that is implemented as

```
- (id) MR_inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)otherContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObject *inContext = [otherContext existingObjectWithID:[self objectID] error:&error];
    [MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];

    return inContext;
}
```

(see https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject%2BMagicalRecord.m).

So both are valid methods to access the object across different contexts,
one using `existingObjectWithID` and the other `objectWithID`.
For the subtle differences between these see the documentation or e.g. [What's the difference between -existingObjectWithID:error: and –objectWithID:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006394/whats-the-difference-between-existingobjectwithiderror-and-objectwithid).